# What are the default maximum RAM allotments for a Silverlight 4 app?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Dealing with an issue where loading a large file into memory in a Silverlight 4 app leads to a an out of memory exception, and a crash. The file is ~100MB. I am trying to determine if Silverlight has some sort of default limit on RAM.

Comment: What type of file is it?  Is it compressed?

Comment: We have to assume that even after compression a file of 100MB could be opened by the user (it's meant to be uploaded to a server), so whether its compressed or not is not a factor. We're not decompressing it before sending it.

Comment: Is there a reason you are loading into memory at all then?

Comment: To upload it to a web service.

Answer (score 3):

I can tell you only about Silverlight 5, as I'm having issue with it now.

As some author has written [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483475/Memory-Limits-in-a-NET-Process), on any machine (x86, or x64) for 32-bit process the memory limit by default is 2 GB. If special flag in .exe header is set (called IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE), then the limit is increased to 4 GB. However, in OOB mode Silverlight app is lauched by C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\sllauncher.exe, which is 32-bit process that doesn't have appropriate flag set, so it has 2GB memory limit MINUS ~800 MB for .NET CLR usage.

### In short terms: RAM limit (at least in my case, OOB mode) is 1.3 GB.

(sorry I'm answering 1.5-years-old question, but people may want to know...)