# Silverlight App hangs and not responds after reaching 1400 to 1500 MB App memory

Tags: web-services, silverlight, memory, memory-leaks

We have a silverlight application and uses Webservices for loading data and database interactions. After continuous usage of App when app memory reaches 1400 to 1500 app is getting slow and hangs no longer responds. I tried with Memory leak profilers like Red Gate Memory profiler and other profilers . Most of them deals with objects which are in live and not getting released and i identified them and fixed them not to hold in memory like objects, event handlers and classses.After fixing this memory is not getting released fully which it is used and after certain usage memory grows to 1500 MB app got hangs.

Is there any possibility where app can run even after 1500 MB usage? is there any setting in webserver or Webservices web.config settings ? or any other solution not to increase memory instantly on usage . Silverlight is creating severe hectic with memory issues. Pls suggest some solution other than checking with memory profiler ?
Getting System out of memory exception once it reaches around 1400 mb and not able to connect to Webservices.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330382/what-are-the-default-maximum-ram-allotments-for-a-silverlight-4-app

Comment: Is there any way to release memory forcefully to maximum ? GC.Collect()
                            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() iam calling these but doesnt release much memory . any ideas ?