# Silverlight. Cannot open web stream for files larger than 4Gb

Tags: c#, silverlight, video-streaming

I have IIS 10 which hosts 2 x mp4 videos. 3 and 4 gb. If I run the following code in console .NET app it works fine. If I run the same in Silverlight 5 the `OpenReadCompleted` is **never fired for 4Gb video but works for 3Gb.**

The IE11 is 64 on Windows 10 x64 and the Silverlight is x64.

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Start();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        //var addr = @"http://localhost/small.mp4";
        var addr = @"http://localhost/large.mp4";

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.OpenReadCompleted += (s, x) =>
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Got result: " + 
                  (x.Result == null ? "null" : 
                    x.Result.CanRead.ToString()));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Got exception {ex}");
            }
        };

        Debug.WriteLine($"Requesting stream {addr}");
        webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(addr));
    }
}
```

The actual task at hand is to make the larger videos (and I have up to 50Gb ones) work with media element. But it never goes past "opening" state. While stripping everything off I found that if I use file stream for large video media element works, but if I try web stream it doesn't, which led me to do the simplest possible test - open web stream alone. And it doesn't work.

This code works in Silverlight for both - small and large videos:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\media\large.mp4", FileMode.Open);
ssme.SetSource(fs);
```

Hence the problem is in the delivery over HTTP.

Any idea on how to investigate further from this point?

**EDIT: For now I just want to open a stream from URL. WebClient doesn't work - any other suggestions how to achieve this?**

Comment: what if you attach to event progress changed of webclient, what would you see?

Comment: is it OOB application? as I know there is hard limitation in memory usage, since downloading allocates 4GB memory it can be the issue. I think you need to play this file as `Stream`

Comment: possible this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330382/what-are-the-default-maximum-ram-allotments-for-a-silverlight-4-app

Comment: Its not OOB. The progress changed fires once showing 524kb loaded and then nothing is happening.

Comment: @Alexey how else can I open stream from URL?